# Error all java and kotlin file in android studio

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, android-studio, gradle

I opened an old project in Android Studio after a few months; But I saw that all `java` and `kotlin` files give errors. but it didn't give an error before!

[image: error-example]

**Could this be due to starting another project?** *(for example, another project has updated gradle files or other things. That's why my old project gives an error)*

**Please help because I am not familiar with gradle and other requirements of android studio.**

[image: information-of-project]

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding your old project? Find the Build menu, then select clean. After cleaning is finished, select Build > Rebuild and see what happens.